# Undefined method new for Google::Cloud::Bigquery:Module in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-bigquery, activeadmin

Hi I am trying to upload data into bigquery dataset from active admin. I have installed the gem `gem 'google-cloud-bigquery', '~> 0.20.1'` but when I try to initialize a new biggquery object it returns me with an error `` undefined method `new' for Google::Cloud::Bigquery:Module ``. Below is my active admin resource :

```
ActiveAdmin.register BabyName do
  require 'google/cloud/bigquery'
  permit_params :name, :gender

  controller do
    def create
      if baby_name = BabyName.create(name: permitted_params[:baby_name][:name], gender: permitted_params[:baby_name][:gender])
        keyfile = '123.json'

        creds = Google::Cloud::Bigquery::Credentials.new keyfile


        bigquery = Google::Cloud::Bigquery.new(
          project_id: 'myproject',
          credentials: creds
        )

        p bigquery.project_id #=> 'my-project'

        dataset = bigquery.create_dataset 'baby'
        table = dataset.create_table 'baby_names' do |schema|
          schema.string 'name', mode: :required
          schema.string 'gender', mode: :required
          schema.integer 'count', mode: :required
        end

        file = File.open 'names/yob2014.txt'

        table.load file, format: 'csv'
        redirect_to admin_baby_name_path(baby_name.id), notice: 'Baby Name saved successfully!!'
      else
        render 'new'
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Please help thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some point to review:

1. The Ruby version

The version 0.20.1 seems old. Please try the latest one [v1.21.0](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-ruby/docs/) and let us know the result.

2. [Ruby authentication](https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-cloud-bigquery/latest/file.AUTHENTICATION.html)

Try the following approaches:

```
Google::Cloud::Bigquery.configure do |config|
  config.project_id  = "my-project-id"
  config.credentials = "path/to/keyfile.json"
end

bigquery = Google::Cloud::Bigquery.new
```

or

```
gcloud = Google::Cloud.new "my-todo-project-id",
                    "/path/to/keyfile.json"
bigquery = gcloud.bigquery
```

I think with this snippet you will be able to use the `bigquery` object.